# Selecting a controller in Laravel depending on the condition

Tags: laravel, routes, controller

I need to create a user accreditation controller. Users can be of two types: Buyer and Seller. I want different controllers to be called at the same address /accreditations/create depending on the type of user.
Now I did this.

```
Route web.php
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('accreditations', AccreditationController::class);
});
```

In the Create method of the AccreditationController

```
public function create()
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    $controllerName = $this->getControllerName($user->role);
    $controller = app()->make($controllerName);
    return $controller->callAction('create', []);
}

protected function getControllerName($id){
     return match ($id) {
         Roles::TRADER=> TraderController::class,
         Roles::BUYER => BuyerController::class,
     };
 }
```

Accordingly, in each controller I made a Create method that calls its own View

```
class TraderController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        return View('Accreditations/CreateTrader', compact('user'));
    }
}
```

Am I doing the right thing or is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Changing what @Herry's answer, you can do

```
public function create(Request $request){
  $user = auth()->user();
  if($user->role=="buyer"){
    return $this->createBuyer($request);
  } else if($user->role=="seller"){
    return $this->createSeller($request);
  } else{
    return $this->createDefault($request);
  }
}

public function createBuyer($request) {
  
}

public function createSeller($request) {
  
}

public function createDefault($request) {
  
}
```

Where you have a single point of entry method `create` then return methods based on the role. Another pro for this way is you can extend as much on the if/else without too much git noise. If both `buyer` and `seller` has the same parts of the code that they run, you can create new method or traits then add them inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

so your case is : you have 2 roles (buyer and seller) and you want your action is depent by roles ?

maybe just need 1 controller and if condition.
so your controller will be like this :

```
public function create(){
  if(role=="buyer"){
    //code for buyer
  }
  else{
    //code for seller
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case, yes. I'm interested in the concept as a whole. If there are more than two roles, the controller method can become very large.